# Can I hide the new messages notification in the Mail icon for only one of my email accounts?

Tags: iphone, email, notifications

Basically I would like to have two email accounts setup on my iPhone 4, one my personal account and one for work.

However for the work account, I'd like to not have it's unread message count included in the number of unread messages displayed as a part of the Mail app's icon (the number in the red circle).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible. "Not possible, without jailbreaking." However, no, I don't know if this already exists in JB-land.

Comment: I'm more concerned with if it's possible without jailbreaking, though I'd be curious if it was possible with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively turn off push notifications for a particular email account... sort of. Go to the Settings app, and hit "Mail, Contacts, Calendars". Go to "Fetch New Data", then scroll down and go to "Advanced". For the email account whose little red badges you don't want, change the setting to "Manual" instead of "Push".

This will prevent new messages from pushing a notification icon to the home screen. However, when you open the Mail app to check your other email, the app will sync the "Manual" account with the server and you'll get a badge if there are unread messages there. So, like bmike mentioned, the real way to get rid of those badges is to get closer to inbox zero.

Answer (score 1):

No - there's no control for that on iOS 4.3 or less. If you disable that account it will temporarily turn it off on counts but the content stays loaded on the device.

I will second the suggestion to set up a separate folder to store the majority of the unread messages and use server side filtering or a manual process to get rid of the distracting/offending messages.

My phone and sanity are both better once I bit the bullet and set up a rule that says if it's unread over a week it goes into my triage later folder. I can still search for messages using spotlight, they are all where I can find them but my phone is faster and the badge is more meaningful without that pile of messages.

I'm not quite to [inbox zero](http://www.43folders.com/izero), but this was a good first step for me to getting there.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no "set this option" way to do it, but I've noticed that a.) the unread count is the number of unread messages in your inbox, not in subfolders and b.) iOS does not automatically check subfolders for new messages unless those subfolders are set to push via Exchange.  So, if your work account is an Exchange account:

-Make a subfolder in your Inbox
-Create a server-side rule to move all messages to that folder.  This can be done in Outlook on your work computer (assuming it's a PC) or probably in the Exchange web client (possibly requiring IE, since they disable certain functionality in the web client for other browsers...).

Then you still have access to the messages in the work account (+1 tap, but it's an iPhone 4, so it's snappy), and they won't show up in your unread count.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry but you are all wrong... there is a way... I've spent the past several hours searching google for a forum for someone who knows... the reason why I know is because someone showed me once... I then reset my phone and the setting was reset and I've been trying for the past several days to remember how I did it.. yes IOS 7 and yes I did it... All I remember was that it wasn't very intuitive so hence why I've now forgotton... if I find it I will repost..

Comment: ok here is how it is done.... Go to Settings - Then Notification Center - Then scroll to where you see the mail box application (whether it is set to be included or not included notification center either spot just find it and click on it). Then you select each mail box that is listed and for the ones you don't want in the "red box" turn the badge ap icon to the off position..wha la !!! take that techies... I did it... I am a working mother of 4 - I am NOT technical and this was super easy... I love that I know how to do something that all these "experts" say "isn't possible..." stick it !!! w

Comment: see my follow up post it is possible !!!!! go to notification center and turn off the badge app icon ... stick it techies who say it can't be done... !!

Comment: If only you had been here three years ago. iOS 7 does have features that iOS 4 lacked